# Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal. C#

Tags: c#

I'm creating a calculator and I've run into an issue if anyone could help me please, that would be greatly appreciated.

Ok, when reaching a certain value in the calculateAera.text it crashes the calculator with an unhandled exception error "System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal." The value is "4.8828125000000004E+29" but I want it to behave like Windows calculator does and carry on until it hits like "9.999999999999999999999999999969e+9919" and then say "Overflow" when it hits the +10000.

Code ->

```
private void calculateAera_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (calculateAera.Text == "" || calculateAera.Text == "0") return;
    decimal number;
    number = decimal.Parse(calculateAera.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency | System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowExponent);
    calculateAera.Text = number.ToString("#,#");
    calculateAera.SelectionStart = calculateAera.Text.Length;
}
```

---

Comment: Then you need to use something that does allow for bigger values. You can try the build in floating point types and live with the imprecise nature of that or you need an external library that allows bigger values and has math operations on that type.

Comment: `Decimal` struct cannot hold values that Windows Calculator can. Use some specialized class, for instance [BigRational on github](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/bcl/blob/master/Libraries/BigRational/BigRationalLibrary/BigRational.cs).

Comment: Even a `double` only goes up to `1.79769313486232e308`, so you'd need some special type to handle this.

Comment: [You can see the source code for Windows Calculator here](https://github.com/microsoft/calculator)

Answer (score 0):

If you need more range, `decimal` simply isn't the tool for the job. C# doesn't really have anything bigger built-in if you want to keep decimal precision.

You'll need to find a different type or write your own. There's no magical solution that just takes the type used in Calculator. Calculator made its own for its own reasons.